# repeat an html pages as a hall

Tags: javascript, html

i wanna ask you how to repeat an html page 10 times and show it in the same page  .

for example :

```
 <html> 
 <body>

 <div id='s1' name='x1' > "bla bla bla " </div>
 <div id='dr' name='dr' > "bla bla bla " </div>
 <div id='cd' name='cd' > "bla bla bla " </div>
 <div id='lm' name='lm' > "bla bla bla " </div>

 <div id='sss'><div id='ooo' > "bla bla bla "</div></div>

  </body></html>
```

so how can i repeat the page - the body - 10 times and show it in the same page ?
note : please forget these answers which have creating divs in the js.

Comment: You'll have to increment the ID's somehow, or use a class. Otherwise, just use `innerHTML`

Comment: What does "as a hall" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny solution :) ->

```
var content = document.body.innerHTML;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    document.body.innerHTML += content;
}
```

**EDIT** if you want serious solution, take a look at [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var body   = document.body.innerHTML;
var output = '';

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  output += body;
}

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```